# What does & return a lvalue or a rvalue?

Tags: c++, rvalue, lvalue

As per textbook .

> The address-of operator (§ 2.3.2, p. 52) requires an lvalue operand and returns
>   a pointer to its operand as an rvalue.

```
int a = 6,c=9;
int *x = &a; //Here x is a lvalue.
x = &c;
```

As per my knowledge if we can assign , it is lvalue .Then why does textbook says address of return rvalue .Can anyone explain me this in layman language

Comment: It is rvalue as said in your quote. You can not assign to the result of `&`  (e.g. `&a = 5;` is an error)

Comment: It says `&a` is an rvalue.

Comment: @M.M yes ! it was supposed to be a

Comment: Which part of the shown code you believe assigns something to `&a`, to support your claim that it's an lvalue? The shown code does not assign anything to `&a`, it assigns `&a` to something else. That's a big difference.

Comment: @problematicDude In `&a`, `&` is the operator and `a` is the operand. Since `a` is an lvalue, the operator `&` can be used and returns an rvalue that is assigned to `x`. Then, variable `x` can be assigned another value (like in `x = &c`) since it is an lvalue.

Comment: Also don't be confused by `"returns a pointer to its operand as an rvalue"`. The *address of* operator doesn't return anything, it provides the *address of* an object (i.e. the memory address where the object is stored). You can't change the memory address, thus it is an *rvalue*. You can change what is stored there, but not the address itself. Know also, `"a pointer is simply a normal variable that stores the address for something else as its value"` No magic.

Comment: The immutability of the value isn't really the crux of whether it's an rvalue or not

Answer (score 1):

Text book says `&a` is an rvalue. I.e. value cannot be assigned to `&a`.
Compilation error will occur if we try to compile below code.

```
int a = 6,c=9;
int *x = &a; //Here x is a lvalue.
&a = x; // Compilation error, as '&a' is an rvalue
```

Comment: This is perhaps a little misleading; immutability is not a core property of rvalues (though it is true that rvalues of built-in type have a sort of enforced immutability to help prevent mistakes)

Answer (score 1):

> As per my knowledge if we can assign

This is not necessarily true in case of class types. But it does always hold for pointers, which you use in the example.

> Then why does textbook says address of return rvalue

Well, you cannot assign to it:

```
&a = &c; // ill formed because &a is rvalue
int *x = &a; // OK. Not an assignment
x = &c;  // OK because x is lvalue
```